# How get width of text show in textview - not all text, just text on screen

Tags: text, width

I have a textview:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Big ideas for a better life"
    android:singleline:"true"
    android:id="@+id/show1" />
```

because singleline and width=100dp, my textview only show

```
Big ideas for a
```

how to mesure width of "Big ideas for a"
or
how to know the text show "Big ideas for a"
????

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` instead